# wait for multiple objects given only a vector of processes that has been created

Tags: c++, process, waitformultipleobjects, multiple-processes

I have a vector of handles from processes I ran using create process. I am wondering how to pass in that into WaitForMultipleObjects(v.size, "code goes here",true, infinite);

I populate the handle vector with the PROCESS_INFORMATION's handle field each time I loop through and create a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11, you could use `v.data()` to get an array of the content in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

WaitForMultipleObjects(v.size(), &v[0], true, INFINITE);